# Azure DevOps Terraform init issue with code in Github

Tags: github, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-modules

I use Azure DevOps Pipelines to run terraform code.
The terraform code and modules stored in connected GitHub repo to Azure Devops Pipelines.
If I not use TF modules - all works fine.
But If I try to use modules which stored in the same repo - I got error during Terrafrom init (when modules are downloaded):

```
Initializing modules...
Downloading git::https://github.com/username/terraform.git?ref=v0.0.1 for storage...
╷
│ Error: Failed to download module
│ 
│ Could not download module "storage" (modules.tf:1) source code from
│ "git::https://github.com/username/terraform.git?ref=v0.0.1": error
│ downloading 'https://github.com/username/terraform.git?ref=v0.0.1':
│ /usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into '.terraform/modules/storage'...
│ fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts
│ disabled
```

For some reason - service connection to GitHub are not enought to download modules. But checout repo, or tf code without modules works fine.

My repo looks like this:

- azure-pipeline.yml
- environments:

  - prod
  - dev
- modules:

  - module_1
  - module_2

For Terraform install, init etc I use provided plugins.

Example of part of pipeline.yml

```
stages:
  - stage: prepare
    displayName: "TF - Init and Plan"
    jobs:
      - job: prepare
        displayName: "Prepare"
        steps:
          - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
            displayName: 'Install Terraform 1.3.6'
            inputs:
              terraformVersion: 1.3.7
              
          - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-release-task.TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: 'Terraform : init'
            inputs:
              workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/environments/dev'
              backendServiceArm: '<subscription_id>'
              backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: <backend_rg_name>
              backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: <backend_storage>
              backendAzureRmContainerName: <backend_container>
              backendAzureRmKey: dev/terrafrom.state

          - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-release-task.TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: 'Terraform : plan'
            inputs:
              command: plan
              workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/environments/dev'
              environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '<subscription_id>'
              backendServiceArm: '<subscription_id>'
              backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: <backend_rg_name>
              backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: <backend_storage>
              backendAzureRmContainerName: <backend_container>
              backendAzureRmKey: dev/terrafrom.state
```

I already tried - [Solution 1](https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform/issues/223)
and [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73898752/terraform-init-and-modules-hosted-in-azure-devops-failed)

But looks like it works only for code which stored in Azure Repos.

I hope exist a way how I can use Azure DevOps with code and modules in GitHub.

Comment: Any chance you have hardcoded where to find the modules to a GitHub address instead of a local path? That’s where I would look right know. 

And you are sure the files are available when you run the command?

Comment: No. I'm not hardcoded - for example (as in TF documentation) "source=github.com/hashicorp/example//modules/vpc?ref=v0.0.1"
And yes, it should be available, because that is the same repo but another tag/branch. And modules exist in that reference.
Also, if I run locally - all works fine.

Comment: Is the problem with one specific module or all and are they in One repo or each module per repo? 
What's the authentication method from your azure pipeline to GitHub DeployKey(SSH) or PAT?

Comment: Ah. If it’s in another branch then that is the problem. Those branches are not downloaded by default to save time and space. 

Use the “fetch depth=0” parameter on the checkout action: https://github.com/actions/checkout

Comment: @ishuar - I use a service connection for Pipelines to Github - [link_docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cross-service/github-integration?view=azure-devops#azure-pipelines-and-github-integration)
The whole code is stored in GitHub. In the same repo but in different folders. Problems with all modules. But if I write code without modules - all works fine.

Comment: @RobBos - I tried that, but unfortunately, it doesn't help. The repo is cloned successfully. The issue is only when TF tries to download the module. For some reason, the service connection does not work for that "checkout".

Comment: could you please confirm if the GitHub repo is private? also could you please a snippet of your terraform code too

Comment: @ishuar - yep, the repo is private

code, for example

`
module "storage" {
  source = "github.com/username/terraform//modules/storage?ref=v0.0.4"

  for_each = local.storages

  name                = "${each.key}storage"
  rg_name             = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  ...
}
`

Comment: Most likely it is a permissions/access issue on the GitHub private repo. Did you set up OAuth Configuration or Personal Access Token for the Github Service connection?
There are ways of configuring SSH Deploy Keys with Github private repo and then using it in the azure DevOps pipeline to fetch the modules. the end goal is to somehow authorize yourself to the private repo either via https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage or SSH key in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a private GitHub repository by the error message it seems that the authorization to the GitHub repo is missing.

As per the [Hashicorp Modules Sources: GitHub](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources#github) documentation, If using the HTTP/HTTPS protocol, or any other protocol that uses username/password credentials, configure [Git Credentials Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) to select a suitable source of credentials for your environment.

Also, you can authenticate via SSH keys with GitHub. The best would be to use [Deploy Keys](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys), which is an SSH key that grants access to a single repository.

**Steps:**

- Create a Deploy Key in your Private repo containing the modules.
- Use this GitHub Documentation on [how to create a deploy key](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys) for reference.

> **Info**: [Generating a new SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key)

- Use Azure DevOps Task [InstallSSHKey@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/install-ssh-key-v0?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) to use the key during execution.

```yaml
          # Install SSH Key for private repo modules {config valid for all private Github Repos with a valid deploy key} ]
          - task: InstallSSHKey@0
            displayName: "Install SSH key for <repo_name> Repo"
            inputs:
              knownHostsEntry: $(knownHostsEntry)
              sshPublicKey: $(sshPublicKey)
              sshKeySecureFile: $(name_of_secure_file_in_library_group) # where private SSH key was upladed
```

```bash
# in Variable Group 
knownHostsEntry = github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==

sshPublicKey = "SSH Public Key generated in the `Generating a new SSH key` step"
```

- Modify your terraform source URLs from https to git

```
module "module_name" {
  source = "github.com/username/terraform//modules/storage?ref=v0.0.4"
  ## CHANGE THIS TO ##
  source = "git@github.com:username/terraform.git//modules/storage?ref=v0.5.1"
}
```

*Still having doubts:* Please use this step-by-step tutorial with screenshots.

https://www.codewithadam.com/using-terraform-modules-from-github-in-azure-devops/